# Load custom list class for a custom class

Tags: c#, list

I have one class which holds a question, and another that is a list of the question class. My goal is to be able to call the constructor of the question list class and pass in a file path to a CSV holding the information for 55 questions. The call should then take this information and generate the list of question objects relative to the data.

I have the information held in a string array however am unsure on how to assign this data to new question objects so I am then able to reference an individual question from the class instance of the question list.

Does anybody have any idea how to proceed?
Here is my code so far:

```
class QuestionBank : List<Question>
{
    public QuestionBank()
    {

    }

    public static QuestionBank GetQuestions(string path)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(path))
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            UTF8Encoding temp = new UTF8Encoding(true);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            while (fs.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length) > 0)
                sb.Append(temp.GetString(bytes));

            MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());

            string[] splitText = sb.ToString().Split(',');
        }

        QuestionBank bank = new QuestionBank()
        {

        };
        return bank;
    }
}
```

Comment: Be careful trying to parse CSV manually, if the question text has a comma in it, your `Split` will fail.

Comment: Why don't you use File.ReadAllText or ReadAllLines  ?

Comment: You could add a property `public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }` to QuestionBank. And inside your GetQuestions just iterate over the items inside `splitText`. And for each splitText-item you create a new question and add it to the Questions-list with `Questions.Add()`. With this solution you can remove the `: List<Question>` inheritance on QuestionBank. Also `ReadAllLines` would be better like auburg mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
public class QuestionBank
{
    private string filePath = "test.csv";
    public List<Question> Questions = new List<Question>();

    public void GetAllQuestions()
    {
        foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(filePath))
        {
            Questions.Add(new Question
            {
                Value = line
            });
        }
    }
}

public class Question
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```